# Getting sum using += doesn't work in here. Why?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to return true or false if given value is narcissistic number.

After assigned empty variable sum, then try to getting sum using +=

But, I don't know It doesn't work in here.

```
function narcissistic(n) {

  let arr =  Array.from(String(n), Number);
  // ex) 999 => [9,9,9]

  let sum;

  arr.forEach((e) => {
    sum += Math.pow(e,arr.length)   ;
  })

  return sum === n ? true: false

}
```

It results in NaN. Have no idea why?
So I had to use this one and It works.

```
function narcissistic(n) {

  let arr =  Array.from(String(n), Number);
  // ex) 999 => [9,9,9]

  let newArr = [];

  arr.forEach((e) => {
     newArr.push(Math.pow(e,arr.length))   ;
  })

  let sum =  newArr.reduce((a,b) => a+b);

  return sum === n ? true: false

}
```

So my question is why the first one doesn't work when it comes to sum += ??

Comment: `let sum = 0;` will fix it

Comment: Narcissistic number?

Comment: unrelated, but `return sum === n ? true: false` is just a verbose and obfuscated way of saying `return sum === n`

Answer (score 4):

You need to make `sum` equal to `0` - it starts out life as `undefined`, and any mathematics with `undefined` leads to `NaN`.

```
let sum = 0;
```

This should fix your problem.

A more concise way to do this is with `reduce`:

```
let sum = arr.reduce((a, c) => a + Math.pow(c, arr.length));
```

Answer (score 0):

We should initialize your variable before referencing.

`let sum = 0;`

It could solve your issue.